# iphone simulator message "My Universal App on Iphone" was does it mean?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, ios-simulator

I run the simulator on a very simple app- a navigation controller contained in a view controller. The application is a view based app with no modification done to the header, and the below code in the implementation.

I get this message "My Universal App on Iphone" superimposed over the subview of the navigation controller and I literally saw one result on google that mentioned it! How do I get rid of this message?

```
#import "[header filename]"

@implementation tutorial_navigationcontrollerAppDelegate

@synthesize window=_window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    //ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    //viewController.title = @"Hello Nav";
    //UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];


    UIViewController *x = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    x.title = @"XXX";
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:x];

    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;




    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {}
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {}
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {}
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {}
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed the same thing while adding a view controller. While I can't explain the label doesn't disappear like it should, I did notice that if you change the controller's view in any way it will remove the text.

```
UIViewController *x = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
x.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Edit: My previous answer did work to a degree, but it turns out it's actually pretty straightforward. Check out MainWindow_iPhone.xib and MainWIndow_iPad.xib. Just delete the labels sitting in the view!

Comment: doh, I should have grepped. I guess that's the folly of doing everything programmatically.